# HQL - join fetch sets parent entity in children

Tags: jpa, hql

I have two entities

```
public class Invoice {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_invoice")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<InvoiceLine> invoiceLineList;
}
```

and

```
public class InvoiceLine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_invoice_line")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Invoice invoice;
}
```

I have an HQL query user for retrieving the invoice with the related invoice lines

```
SELECT i FROM Invoice as i left outer join fetch i.invoiceLineList as invoiceLines WHERE i.id=(:id)
```

the invoice is correctly retrieved, but the problem is that in the list of invoice line, the object "invoice" is set. This is a big problem because I have a method which serializes this invoice and it returns a StackOverflow exception (invoice -> invoiceLine -> invoice -> invoiceLine -> ... )

How can I avoid this parent entity set?

Comment: In InvoiceLine entity, you really have a recursion? Or you confused when writing the code? I have the impression that the last line of InvoiceLine would not `private List<InvoiceLine> invoiceLineList;` but `private Invoice invoice;`.

Comment: Does a `for` loop and set to null to _invoice_ would not be simpler?

Comment: Sure, but I'd like to avod this kind of workaround (so that I can avoid this kind of problem at all)